# Unique Bootstrap Table Label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-tables

I've been trying to mimic the Bootstrap tables found in the documents section of their website:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables

I like how the table has the Label "Example" in it.  However, rather than displaying the same table name I wanted to display a unique label for each separate table (In my case showing different years).  It seems simple enough but something isn't working right.

My HTML:

```
<div id="2003" class="bs-docs-example">
  <table class="table table-striped">
...

<div id="2013" class="bs-docs-example">
  <table class="table table-striped">
...
```

My CSS:

```
/*Original CSS from Bootstrap*/
.bs-docs-example:after {
content: "Example";
position: absolute;
top: -1px;
left: -1px;
padding: 3px 7px;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
color: #9da0a4;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
-moz-border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
 border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
}

/*My additional CSS*/
#2003.bs-docs-example:after {
content: "2003";
}

#2013.bs-docs_example:after {
content: "2013";
}
```

**UPDATE:** I did a fiddle.  Check it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qp4kg/3/

Comment: Put it on jsFiddle. We then have easily check and correct it.

Comment: Although html5 allows id's that begin with a number (I think), try starting with a letter.

Comment: @WooCaSh Done.  Take a look at the fiddle.

Comment: @Keven Look please on answer.

Comment: @d3vkit You were right man.  HTML5 doesn't like numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot copy one rule for class `bs-docs-example`:

```
.bs-docs-example {
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px 0;
    padding: 39px 19px 14px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/Qp4kg/3/

### Important:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: Great, I updated my fiddle.  Any reason why they both have a label of "Example"?  I want one to have 2003 and the other to have 2013.

Comment: hah!  Really?  So @d3vkit was right all along when he said HTML5 didn't accept numbers first...  Thanks a lot man.

Comment: It's good practice to vote up answer too if is good. I'm happy that I can help :) Like I said with jsFiddle is much more easier to fix something :)